# Is jaxrs:server required for cxf:rsServer when using camel?

Tags: rest, jax-ws, jax-rs, apache-camel, cxfrs

I'm struggling to get a simple cxf:rsServer to listen on a port.
My appContext:

```
<bean id="transformer" class="com.xyxx.portlistener.services.Transformer">
</bean> 

<cxf:rsServer id="pushServer" 
              address="tcp://localhost:9090/hrm/hrm_push?bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer;resourceClasses=com.xyxx.portlistener.services.Transformer" >
    <cxf:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="transformer" />
    </cxf:serviceBeans>
</cxf:rsServer>          

<!--  Camel Configuration -->
<camel:camelContext id="camel-1"  xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <package>com.xyxx.portlistener.services</package> 
    <camel:route id="route1">
           <camel:from uri="cxfrs://bean://pushServer"/> 
           <camel:to uri="log:TEST?showAll=true" />
    </camel:route>            
</camel:camelContext>
```

My exception:

```
MethodInvocationException: Property 'serviceBeans' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
```

My camel version 2.4.0 pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-hl7</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-mina</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

3 confusing issues with HTTP and that exception

1. I'm running camel as standalone so I don't think I need a Servlet.
2. pushServer is using tcp:// not http:/
3. transformer is a pojo and knows nothing about HTTP

Question: [In most of the xml examples regarding cxf:rsServer](http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html#CXFRS-HowtoconfiguretheRESTendpointinCamel) I've seen jaxrs:server configured.  That is one thing I do not have.  Do I need it?
Thanks for reading.  All suggestions are welcome.

Andrew

Comment: I resolved the NoClassDef issue by adding camel-http to the pom.  I still would like to know if the jaxrs:server is needed by cxfrs.  They are probably not but I'm not sure why the code is in the examples I'm seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `jaxrs:server` shown in the examples is simulating a remote REST web service to complete the routing example.

- Route From: cxf:rsServer
- Route To: cxf:rsClient

The CXF RS client needs to send the message somewhere, which is what the JAX RS server running on a different port is used for.

Since your route destination above is something else (a log component) you have no need for the JAX RS server configuration.